# I created a new sidenav in StackBlitz and I want to adapt it to my project of Angular Material. Where to start?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

** Edit: ** 
The solution for this case in specific was not conceived through an extend, but rather something simpler, giving it a simpler approach.

**Scenario :**

- Recently with the help of the community and seeing examples I got the sidenav that I wanted to use in my project.
- The problem is that I did it in Stackblitz and I have a hard time
  adapting it to my current project so that I have this new sidenav.
- This is the sidenav in stackblitz: [Stackblitz sidenav](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-k81zfl)

**Question :** 
Is there any way to pass the component that I have stackblitz to my component already created in the project (Which has its respective methods and functions) without having to erase what I already have?
And here's my project code:

**app-header.component.html**

```html
<!--- Toolbar starts here-->
<div class="container-toolbar">
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="fixed-header">

<button
type="button"
aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
mat-icon-button
(click)="drawer.toggle()">
<mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
</button>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<button type="button" mat-icon-button href="">
<mat-icon matTooltip="Salir">exit_to_app</mat-icon>
</button>


</mat-toolbar>
</div>

<!--- Sidenav starts here -->
<mat-sidenav-container style="height:100%;width:100%;">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer fixedInViewport="true"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'side' : 'push'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async)" style="box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #999;z-index: 2;">
     <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item>
          <a routerLink="/dashboard">Static 1</a>
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon>home</mat-icon>
          </mat-list-item>
          <mat-list-item>
          <a routerLink="/parametros">Static 2</a>
          <mat-icon mat-list-icon>tune</mat-icon>
          </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
            <a routerLink="/#">Static 3</a>
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>settings</mat-icon>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
            <a routerLink="/#">Static 4</a>
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>layers</mat-icon>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item (click)="showSubmenu = !showSubmenu" class="parent">
              <span class="full-width" *ngIf="isExpanded || isShowing">No static</span>
              <mat-icon mat-list-icon>flash_on</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon class="menu-button" [ngClass]="{'rotated' : showSubmenu}" *ngIf="isExpanded || isShowing">expand_more</mat-icon>
            </mat-list-item>
   <div class="submenu" [ngClass]="{'expanded' : showSubmenu}" *ngIf="isShowing || isExpanded">
          <mat-list-item>
              <a routerLink="/#">Options 1</a>
              </mat-list-item>
              <mat-list-item>
                <a routerLink="/#">Options 2</a>
                </mat-list-item>
        <h2 matSubheader class="mat-submenu-title"><mat-icon>account_balance</mat-icon>  Test</h2>
    <mat-list-item (click)="showSubSubMenu = !showSubSubMenu" class="parent">
     <span class="full-width" *ngIf="isExpanded || isShowing">Test</span>
     <mat-icon class="menu-button" [ngClass]="{'rotated' : showSubSubMenu}" *ngIf="isExpanded || isShowing">expand_more</mat-icon>
    </mat-list-item>
    <div class="submenu" [ngClass]="{'expanded' : showSubSubMenu}" *ngIf="isShowing || isExpanded">
          <mat-list-item>
            <a routerLink="/topupcard">test</a>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
              <a routerLink="/#">test</a>
              </mat-list-item>
            <h2 matSubheader class="mat-submenu-title"><mat-icon>card_travel</mat-icon> test</h2>
            <mat-list-item>
              <a routerLink="/#">test</a>
              </mat-list-item>
              <mat-list-item>
                <a routerLink="/#">test</a>
                </mat-list-item>
        </div>

   </div>
  </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**App-header.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './app-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-header.component.css']
})
export class AppHeader {
 isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches)
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;
  isExpanded = true;
  showSubmenu = false;
  isShowing = false;
  showSubSubMenu = false;

  onmouseenter() {
    if (!this.isExpanded) {
      this.isShowing = true;
    }
  }

  onmouseleave() {
    if (!this.isExpanded) {
      this.isShowing = false;
    }
  }

}
```

I used schematics at the beginning to create it, 
But then I modified it to be able to have the front as I wanted it.

I have tried to adapt it several times, but the amount of errors it gives me are so many that I do not know where to start. I have little time working with angular, if someone could tell me where to start ...

**Solution:**
If someone else finds this task, simply create a component in your project based on the Stackblitz, then simply call the selector from your project (Inside the stackblitz component, look at the router-outlet, as it could give problems, I I deleted it and I called it from the component that I had in my project and it worked) Of rest is to edit the CSS of the component of Stackblitz so that it adapts to your needs.

Comment: If you have errors, it would be wise to post the said errors, and not the code of something that is working ...

Comment: What happens is that directly my question is focused on how I could begin to adapt it, rather than the errors it gave me.

Comment: Create a npm module ? Make your framework versions match ? How could we know !

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to incorporate what I have in the Stackblitz component in my app-header.component.ts component (without deleting what already exists as it is what makes the sidebar toggleable), in order to pass Stackblitz's HTML to my code and from there start to fix what is needed.

Comment: You have a download button in stackblitz, download the zip file and copy paste the code ?

Comment: Seriously, that's totally unclear, you should really post your errors and stop this general, open-ended questionning.

Comment: It would not be necessary to download it, but that is not what I am asking, Im asking about how to pass that Stackblitz component to my already created component without erasing the functions and methods that are already in it, to maintain the two classes. since it has its own class declared with all its methods, etc.

Comment: @trichetriche 
You're right, and I'm going to edit it. The question really would be how can I pass the code of that Stackblitz component to my current component, without erasing what it already has, that is if there is any way from angular or I have to create a new component.

Comment: So you want to use `export class MySidenav extends StackblitzSidenav` ?

Comment: @trichetriche 
The truth is that I have not understood what you want to say because as I mentioned I have little time with Angular. Basically I want to know the correct way to put all the methods and classes that I have in the Stackblitz component, in the component of my project called 'app-header.component.ts' without having to erase what it has inside, since my objective is to unite them.

Comment: `extends` is an algorithm concept called inheritance, it has nothing to do with Angular. I have understood your need (i already did the first time), what I'm telling you is that I'm not a medium and I need errors to work on.

Comment: I understand perfectly, but could you help me start making the extend? how would you put it in this case? So I can see what errors come out and if I can not solve them, ask for help here.

Comment: Exactly as i have written it ... That's seriously not difficult, the only thing to do is write `extends`, `super()` in the constructor (with the correct dependencies of course), and you have successfully merged your two classes.

Comment: If you could give me the example it would be better, so I can see and understand it. I'm a bit blocked right now and I need help, I really apologize for the inconvenience!

Comment: No problem, [here you go](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5xefi-k3ziug?file=app/extended-sidenav.ts)

Comment: Today I am clearer and I managed to fix it, I edited the question and added the solution. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That's not what you asked, the solution you have provided doesn't extend anything but uses your sidenav as an external component. But if it suits you, good enough ! good luck for your project, see you around :)

Comment: It's true, in fact I realized that the solution was focusing it badly because through an extend it was complicating the code more.